# Type of a wildcard object without using "instanceof"

Tags: java

In the code below, I don't want to use `instanceof` to know the type of repository.
Is it the only way to get the type? Is it possible to know de type with the wildcard `RepositoryVet<?>`? This would save me doing lots of test.

```
public ArrayList<String> rechercherTabTailles(String sexe,String SI,RepositoryVet<?> repository) {
    ArrayList<String> tabTailles;
    repository.Open();
    repository.rechercherspin(sexe);
    if (SI.compareTo("US") ==  0) {
        if (repository instanceof ChaussureRepository) 
            tabTailles= ((ChaussureRepository) repository).taillesUS;
        if (repository instanceof ChemiseRepository) 
            tabTailles= ((ChemiseRepository) repository).taillesUS;
    }
}
```

To complete my question :
RepositoryVet is already an abstractClass defined like this :

public abstract class RepositoryVet implements IRepositoryVet {

```
public ArrayList<String> taillesEU;
public ArrayList<String> taillesUS;
public ArrayList<String> taillesUK;
public ArrayList<String> taillesIT;
public ArrayList<String> taillesJP;
public ArrayList<String> taillescm;
public ArrayList<String> taillesinch;
```

etc....
}

And "ChaussureRepository" is a class that extends RepositoryVet like this :

public class ChaussureRepository extends RepositoryVet {

```
public ArrayList<String> taillesEU;
public ArrayList<String> taillesUS;
public ArrayList<String> taillesUK;
public ArrayList<String> taillesIT;
public ArrayList<String> taillesJP;
public ArrayList<String> taillescm;
public ArrayList<String> taillesinch;
```

etc....

Comment: What do you mean by wildcard object? A superclass? And what's wrong with `instanceof`?

Comment: Subclasses of `RepositoryVet` (which is what you can test for using `instanceof`) are not (directly) related to the type parameter of `RepositoryVet`.

Comment: It'd be better to have `repository` subclass some generic type for which this would work in general, maybe?

Comment: @TedHopp : The subclasses are related to RepositoryVet like above. Meaby it's not the good declaration??

Comment: A side note: 1.) Those public lists would violate encapsulation and are generally not a good design, try to make them private/protected and add appropriate getters/setters (or better add/get/remove methods). 2.) You should not define the lists again in the subclass, since those would shadow the lists in the super class and would lead to hard to find bugs. Instead, just use the lists defined in the super class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use a property in the repository to represent the type, e.g. an enum.
You'd still need some tests though.

However, in your case, inheritance might be the better approach: create a common interface that provides a method `List<String> getTaillesUS()` (or maybe `List<String> getTailles(TailesType tailesType)` (where `TailesType` would be an enum with at least the value `US`).